# Segmentation fault pointer to a reference

Tags: c++, pointers

I was trying out some code of Scott Meyers Effective C++, item 3 in particular.

The code in his book should be very similar to this (he left out the constructor)

```
#include <iostream>


class TextBlock {
public:
    TextBlock(char* ptr) : ptrText(ptr)
    {}
     char& operator[](std::size_t pos) const {
        return ptrText[pos];
    }
private :
    char* ptrText;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const TextBlock block("Hello");
    std::cout << block[0] << std::endl;
    char* ptr = &block[0];
    *ptr = 'J';
    std::cout << block[0];
}
```

At the point where I change the contents in the pointer ptr (*ptr = 'J';), I get a segmentation fault (which normally happens when dereferencing an uninitialized or freed pointer).  This is not happening here, what is going wrong at `*ptr = 'J'`;

Comment: A pointer to a reference is impossible.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, Just as irrelevant as the title ;)

Comment: @chris: Sorry, I didn't notice the title.

Comment: If you enable compiler warnings, it should tell you exactly what you're doing wrong. (And in C++11, it should be an error).

Answer (score 4):

`TextBlock` does not own any storage.  It was pointing at a constant string in memory `"Hello"` and you've tried to modify the read-only contents.

If you declared a local variable with its own storage, this would work, such as:

```
char test[32] ;
strcpy( test, "Hello") ;
const TextBlock block( test) ;
char * ptr= &block[0] ;

*ptr= 'J' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should manage

> ptrText

member not as a pointer that point to a constant memory region where write is forbidden, but as a reference to a stack-based or heap-based object that you can fully control.

you can use char array instead

```
#include <iostream>

#define MAX_LENGTH = 1024

class TextBlock {
public:
TextBlock(char* ptr)
{
    memset(ptrText, 0, MAX_LENGTH);
    memcpy(ptrText, ptr, strlen(ptr) < MAX_LENGTH?strlen(ptr):MAX_LENGTH);
}

char& operator[](std::size_t pos) const {
    return ptrText[pos];
}
private :
char ptrText[MAX_LENGTH];
```

};

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>


class TextBlock {
public:
    TextBlock(char* ptr) : ptrText(ptr)
    {}
     char& operator[](std::size_t pos) const {
        return ptrText[pos];
    }
private :
    char* ptrText;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char text[] = "Hello";
    const TextBlock block(text);
    std::cout << block[0] << std::endl;
    char* ptr = &block[0];
    *ptr = 'J';
    std::cout << block[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yep this is true!
ptrText is just record the ptr of "hello",and "hello" is const static text that you can't change.It didn't store anything~so you can't change it.